# How can i use long-clicks in MonoDroid?

Tags: android, events, mono, xamarin.android

in the moment i'm using long-clicks this way:

```
button.SetOnLongClickListener(new MyLongClickListener());

public class MyLongClickListener : View.IOnLongClickListener
{
    public bool OnLongClick(View v)
    {
        //do something pretty cool
        return true;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

But writing a class just to do an easy one or two-liner in the OnLongClick-method seems not to be very smart. So i'm wondering if there is a better solution?

Comment: Completely unrelated, but _do not_ implement IJavaObject.Handle yourself when implementing Java interfaces. Instead, inherit from Java.Lang.Object and inherit it's implementation of Android.Runtime.IJavaObject. http://android.xamarin.com/Documentation/Architecture/Android_Callable_Wrappers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach of writing a listener class is the way to do it in Java, which is why it's exposed as such in Mono for Android. That said, in Mono for Android you can assign a delegate of type [LongClickHandler](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.Views.View.LongClickHandler) to the [LongClick](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.Views.View.LongClick) property if you'd prefer that. if you'd prefer that.

```
view.LongClick = onLongClick;

private bool onLongClick(View view) 
{
    // do some stuff

    return true;
}
```

or

```
view.LongClick = (clickedView) =>
{
    // do some stuff

    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

See this example code:

```c#
[Activity(Label = "My Activity", MainLauncher = true)]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);            
    SetContentView(Resource.layout.main);

    Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.id.button);
    TextView view = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.id.text);

    button.Click += (s, args) => view.Text = "Clicked!";
    button.LongClick += (s, args) =>
                            {
                                view.Text = "Long click!";
                                args.ReturnValue = false;
                            };
}
}
```

Comment: Example code should work for event handler. button.Click is an event handler. Unfortunately button.LongClick is a property and the code above is not working. (Operator "+=" cannot be applied to operators of type Android.Views.View.LongClickHandler and 'lambda expression')

Comment: @andineupert did you find the solution for `Android` I am also facing the same issue